# Is it possible to search for an item in the entire sharepoint site?

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, sharepoint-2010, wpf-controls

I have been trying to build a WPF application using REST API for searching. I have been able to get the item searched in a particular list but I want it to be searched in the entire site. And I want to display everything related to that search item (like discussions, URLs, description etc). 
I have 2 questions w.r.t. this::

1) How to search in the entire site for a particular item?

2) How do I display the search results obtained in a clear readable manner? Which WPF control should be used for the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

1. To find results for search you must configure the [search
   crawler](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010/) in central admin for that site. After updating all your
   items in the site just set the crawler. Now you can search for an
   item. Suppose if you update any items in the sharepoint then run
   that crawler again. So all updated values also comes in sharepoint
   search.
2. You have to do programmatic approach for WPF control with search APIs. After this in Sharepoint designer for the search control icon you have to change the redirect url to page in which your control contains with required parameters. If you leave about WPF control then you can edit the xslt for the search result to show in cleaner way.. Find this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/how-to-edit-display-of-search-results-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: Thnx for the reply. But I have to basically code everything in a WPF application in Visual Studio. Sharepoint designer is not a option for my requirements.